# Compare 2 similar arrays and remove all similar items in the beginning

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 similar arrays:

```
  $array_a = array(
    array(
      "id" => 1,
      "merchant_reference" => "12345"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 2,
      "merchant_reference" => "67890"
    )
  );

  $array_b = array(
    array(
      "id" => 1,
      "merchant_reference" => "12345"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 2,
      "merchant_reference" => "67890"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 3,
      "merchant_reference" => "12345"
    )
  );
```

The only difference is `$array_b` has an additional item. I'd like to output a new array that counts the total keys of `$array_a` and removes all keys in `$array_b` up to that count. And, just leave the 3rd item in `$array_b`.

I've tried:

```
function compare_arrays($array1, $array2) {
    $array1_count = count($array1);
    $array2_count = count($array2);
    $array2_count = $array2_count - $array1_count;
    $array2 = array_slice($array2, $array1_count, $array2_count);

    return $array2;
}
```

But, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: The first array is created at 12 PM - and the second array is created at 5 PM, and contains data from the first array plus any new data that was added after 12 PM. So both arrays will always be equal and the items will be the same up until 12 PM; there after the items are new. The second case would not happen either. 

Thanks, will use the code as is.

Comment: @Dakarai Are both arrays uniformly arranged this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion under comment, your code is fine, just an additional conditional check which will improve execution time in case no addition after 12 pm is found.

```
function compare_arrays($array1, $array2) {
    $array1_count = count($array1);
    $array2_count = count($array2);
    $array2_count = $array2_count - $array1_count;
    if($array2_count > 0){
        return $array2 = array_slice($array2, $array1_count, $array2_count);
    }
    return $array1;
}
```